# Regex to return last found pattern?

Tags: regex

I am having problems with my regex. It's returning the first match when I want it to return the last match.

Regex Pattern:

```
(?si)&chg_id= *?(.*?)\"
```

String being searched:

Display charges for the period 2010-05-04 11:21:00 to 2010-06-10 23:59:59

```
<A HREF="index.php?function=view_all_mobile&plan_id=224158&chg_id=1861161"><P>Display the period 2010-06-11 00:00:00 to 2010-07-10 23:59:59</A>
<A HREF="index.php?function=view_all_mobile&plan_id=224158&chg_id=2033934"><P>Display the period 2010-07-11 00:00:00 to 2010-08-10 23:59:59</A>
<A HREF="index.php?function=view_all_mobile&plan_id=224158&chg_id=2217641"><P>Display the period 2010-08-11 00:00:00 to 2010-09-10 23:59:59</A>
<A HREF="index.php?function=view_all_mobile&plan_id=224158&chg_id=2411848"><P>Display the period 2010-09-11 00:00:00 to 2010-10-10 23:59:59</A>
<A HREF="index.php?function=view_all_mobile&plan_id=224158&chg_id=2615705"><P>Display the period 2010-10-11 00:00:00 to 2010-11-10 23:59:59</A>
<A HREF="index.php?function=view_all_mobile&plan_id=224158&chg_id=2830781"><P>Display the period 2010-11-11 00:00:00 to 2010-12-10 23:59:59</A>
```

My expression is returning 1861161 but I want it to return 2830781 instead.

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. I am using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to test the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a DOM parser and grab all anchors on the page ( `getElementsByTagName('a')` ), get their href ( `getAttribute('href')` ), filter based on the href value, then grab the last one that matches the pattern?